# Why is my simple jQuery fade-in/out script not working?

Tags: jquery, html

I just started learning jQuery, and I'm trying to look into how to have an advertisement fade in over some content, then disappear when a button is clicked. Starting simply, I just am trying to fade an image in, then fade it out when I click a button. Also, it would be nice if someone could tell me how to make it slide up and little bit after it fades in. I would appreciate any help.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function() {
                    $('#ad').delay(2000).fadeIn('slow');

                $('continue').click(function() {
                    $('#ad').fadeOut('normal');
            });
        });
```

and the HTML

```
<img id="ad" src="images/nameofimage.jpg" alt="" width="165" height="100" /> 
    <button id="continue">Continue</button>
```

Comment: I suggest you use [fadeTo()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) instead of fadeIn() or fadeOut().  It's more flexible and will eliminate some behavior you won't want.  This code is fine, but fadeTo is a little nicer.

Answer (score 3):

Which part isn't working?

The first thing I noticed was that were missing the # before continue;

```
$('#continue').click(function()
```

Comment: As most of the other answerers have pointed out, there is a lot of missing code that is required to achieve the whole of what you are trying to do. I've started with the assumption that you have that sorted, and I have focused on what I can see. But, if you need more help than this, you'll need to be more specific.

Comment: For example, I've assumed that you have both the image and button already hidden and absolutely positioned over you page using CSS.

Answer (score 2):

To fade in #ad, it needs to be hidden first. You can just add that on top of your chain, like so:

```
$('#ad').hide().delay(2000).fadeIn('slow');
```

This will hide the object when the DOM is ready, wait 2 seconds, then fade in.

Though you can achieve your sliding effect with the more capable (and complex) .animate() method:

```
$('#ad').css("opacity", 0).delay(2000).animate({ marginTop: "-=10", opacity: 1}, 500);
```

This would set the opacity of the object to 0, wait 2 seconds, and simultaneously fade in and move the object up 10 pixels. This is a bit verbose as chains go, though.

Also of note that setting opacity to 0 will keep it in the document flow, where as .hide() is equivalent to display: none;

And yes, as Matt Tew says above, you forgot the hash in your click handler.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't hide your image at initial stages, even tho your functions are working fine, users won't see any effect. So either use `display:none` css rule or `hide()` function to hide it first and use the fadeIn() effect.

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $('#ad').hide().delay(2000).fadeIn('slow');

    $('#continue').click(function () {
        $('#ad').fadeOut('normal');
    });
});
```

And also `continue` should be id or class or and element. Since there is no such element, please specify which type it is -id or class.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems here.

- The code wants to start with a fade in of an element that is already visible.  Try making it hidden first then fade in
- The 'continue' selector is missing the '#' prefix to make it on an id

Updated Code

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $('#ad').hide();
    $('#ad').delay(2000).fadeIn('slow');

    $('#continue').click(function() {
        $('#ad').fadeOut('normal');
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w2Ycy/